# Unreal Engine 4 - Android NDK - Visual Studio - sys/cdefs.h - "No function renaming possible"

Tags: visual-studio, android-ndk, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to compile Unreal Engine 4 project including Android NDK in Visual Studio 2013, but there's an error occurring I don't know how to address

```
PublicIncludePaths.Add("D:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include");
```

**D:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include\sys/cdefs.h(252): fatal error C1189: #error :  "No function renaming possible"**

Here's code responsible for the error

```
#ifdef __lint__
#define __RENAME(x) __symbolrename(x)
#else
#error "No function renaming possible"
#endif /* __lint__ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me! I was trying to compile the source code for Unreal Editor, in other words for Windows. Using Editor Launch/Package for Android is the right way to compile with Android NDK headers.

**.Build.cs**

```
if ((Target.Platform == UnrealTargetPlatform.Android))
{
    PublicIncludePaths.Add("D:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include");
}
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "Android/AndroidApplication.h"
...
JNIEnv* Env = FAndroidApplication::GetJavaEnv();
jint VersionJint = Env->GetVersion();
int8 Version = (int8)VersionJint;
GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(2, 0.5f, FColor::Cyan, FString::FromInt(Version));
```

Looks like I need exceptions for all #includes too.